# Understanding this theorem about continuity at $c$ and a sequence converging to $c$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

I want someone to explain to me just this part:

> Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c\in D$. Then $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if, whenever $X_n$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $c$, then $f(X_n)$ converges to $f(c)$.

1. How can we apply this definition in an example? Please give any example and apply this theorem?
2. How we can choose the sequence? Is there a general rule or does it depend on the example?

Comment: for part 2), this must be true for ANY sequence $\{{X_n}\}$ converging to $c$, you cannot choose one in particular.
By the way,you should be more precise about what exactly is $D$.

Answer (score 1):

We only ever choose a *specific* sequence when we wish to show a function is ***not*** continuous.  Another way to write your theorem is to say that the function $f$ is not continuous at $c$ if and only if there is some sequence $X_n \rightarrow c$ such that $f(X_n)$ does not converge to $f(c)$.  This is probably the more practical way of using it.

To show $f$ is continuous using this sequential method, we would need to show that for **EVERY POSSIBLE** sequence $X_n \rightarrow c$, that $f(X_n) \rightarrow c$.  Showing $f$ is continuous by examining every possible sequence is something I personally haven't seen all that often.